# How to display jquery querySelector selected file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I created a file upload using jquery querySelector. How can i display The selected file name in a span after selection?

My html code is

```
<span id="filename"></span>
<input type="file" id="fileElem" name="file">
<button class="buttonsCss" id="fileSelect">Upload resume</button>
```

Js code is

```
document.querySelector('#fileSelect').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          // Use the native click() of the file input.
          e.preventDefault();
          document.querySelector('#fileElem').click();
      }, false);
```

How can i display file name in span #filename

An help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: how to get "value" of file upload input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282080/jquery-how-to-get-value-of-file-upload-input-field)

Comment: just a note, querySelector is not a jquery method, neither is addEventListener, those are native javascript methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a listener for the onchange event and then access the `files` list

```
document.querySelector('#fileElem').onchange = function(e){
   var files = this.files;
   var name = files[0].name;
   document.querySelector("#filename").innerHTML = name;
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WNJJd/1/)

Comment: This is not working in IE 9, is there is any fix available for solving it?